# Why is that my "loadedmetadata" event always work on my main google account browser while it only sometimes work on my other account?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I noticed that whenever I executed the loadedmetadata event listener in my main google account browser, it always logs loaded successfully after multiple reloads.

However, when I opened that same webpage/html on my other google account browser, sometimes it does not log successfully. The event listener does not get triggered sometimes in my other google browser.

In this context, pupHymn is an audio element.

```
let pupHymn = document.querySelector("#pup-hymn");

const init = () => {
pupHymn.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", (evt) => {
    console.log('loaded');
   });
}

init();
```

I observed this when the code inside my event listener started not getting executed when I switched to another google account when I did not want to close my tabs in my main account for a certain recording code demo.